# Flatten a JSON Object with a nested object to flattened fields

Tags: android, serialization, jackson, android-room

I am using Android's Room and Jackson to persist incoming JSONObjects/JSONArrays as POJOs/Entities.

From one end point, I am getting a response in this form:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "name"
  "dob": 12421414,

  "address": {
    "number": 11,
    "street":"some street",
    "City": "A city"
  }
}
```

I want to deserialize the "address" nested JSON object in to the POJO as a simple 1 dimensional object/entity as shown:

```
@Entity
public class myEntity{

    @PrimaryKey
    @NotNull
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private int dob;

    //Address flattened:
    private int addressNumber;
    private String addressStreet;
    private String addressCity; 

    //Getters and setters

}
```

How can I go about this? It is as though I want to call a method to take the @JsonProperty("address") and assign the fields.

Comment: Have you tried adding the @Embedded(prefix = "address_") ?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize by implementing address setter method.

Add this setter method in `myEntity` class:

```
@JsonSetter
    public void setAddress(JsonNode text){
        this.addressNumber = text.get("number").asInt();
        this.addressStreet = text.get("street").asText();
        this.addressCity = text.get("City").asText();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@embedded was the simplest method and worked well.

Answer (score -1):

Use Gson library for this it pretty easily solves your purpose.

1.First add the dependency for this in your build.gradle file-

```
 implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

2. Make a class from the json for your case the class would be:

   ```
   public class MyEntity{

       @SerializedName("id")
       @Expose
       public int id;
       @SerializedName("name")
       @Expose
       public String name;
       @SerializedName("dob")
       @Expose
       public int dob;
       @SerializedName("address")
       @Expose
       public Address address;

       }
   ```

3.Setting Pojo :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyEntity entity= gson.fromJson(br, MyEntity.class);
```

4.All done now access pojo -

```
Log.d("Data",entity.name);
```

Comment: You'r not answering the question with "public Address address;". He doesn't want an adress fiield.